# Option for Web forms is missing under web folder when creating web application in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, web

[NO SUBMENU UNDER WEB FOLDER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exYYi.jpg)

I want to create ASP.NET Server Control.
But i can see only ASP.NET Empty Web Application.
i need to create in framework 3.5
Is there anything missing to install or it is available in VS2017 community edition?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, what you refer abour server control ( maybe usercontrol?) when you install vs2017 community edition for example you install asp.net too, you always have to create a new proyect (asp net empty application) to have controls inside the project.

Comment: I need asp.net server control as the project type

Comment: read the last post, maybe, you have the same problem https://forums.asp.net/t/2099538.aspx?Does+VS2015+support+creating+custom+ASP+NET+Server+Controls+

Comment: but i didn't get the option for selecting asp.net server control under web

Comment: please see the attached image

Comment: you can create any asp control under asp web application project and an asp web site.

Answer (score 0):

The option for asp.net webform is missing because you've not installed the ASP.NET web development module. Install the APS.NET Web Development Module in visual studio and the issue will be fixed. [video](https://youtu.be/7F0YnLC1wbI)